# Bellman Ford algorithm for multiple negative cycles

Tags: algorithm, graph, bellman-ford

is it possible to modify Bellman Ford algorithm to detect and print several negative cycles?

Comment: Do you mean that, instead of stopping when a negative cycle is detected, the algorithm continues with the possibility of detecting additional negative cycles?